# How to get title inside table using HtmlAgility pack?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

Hello I am trying to get the "title" element out of this table:

```
<td class="field_domain"><a href="/goto/1/f4gw3/52/?tr=search" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="PlantarFasciitisHeelPain.com"><strong>Plantar</strong><strong>Fasciitis</strong>HeelPain.com</a></td>
```

Here is my code that almost works but not quite:

```
Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("https://www.expireddomains.net/domain-name-search/?o=domainpop&r=d&q=plantar+fasciitis")
        Dim html As String = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
        Dim tabletag = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='field_domain']")


        For Each t In tabletag
            Dim var = t.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='title']").InnerText
            MessageBox.Show(var)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb()
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("https://www.expireddomains.net/domain-name-search/?o=domainpop&r=d&q=plantar+fasciitis")
Dim html As String = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml

For Each linkItem As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='field_domain']")
    Dim name = linkItem.Element("a").InnerText
    MessageBox.Show(name)


Next
```